# Azure AIP Scanner - Data Discovery error

Tags: azure

I am having an issue with AIP Scanner.

The scan goes fine but the "**Data Discovery**" section within AIP Azure throws an error: "Temporary issue" and shows no data.

Some of my co-workers are having the exact same issue, so I ruled out it could be due to permissions.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: The error message is vague enough that the only people who are going to be able to assist with this are MS support.

Comment: I see. I will do so. Thanks!